# How to 'Pipe' Binary Data in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have an RDD containing binary data.  I would like to use 'RDD.pipe' to pipe that binary data to an external program that will translate it to string/text data.  Unfortunately, it seems that Spark is mangling the binary data before it gets passed to the external program.

This code is representative of what I am trying to do.  What am I doing wrong? How can I pipe binary data in Spark?

```
bin = sc.textFile("binary-data.dat")
csv = bin.pipe ("/usr/bin/binary-to-csv.sh")
csv.saveAsTextFile("text-data.csv")
```

Specifically, I am trying to use Spark to transform pcap (packet capture) data to text/csv so that I can perform an analysis on it.

Comment: Wait, do you *have* the RDD containing binary data, or do you need to run an external program to create it ? Running the program **once** you have the binary data is a classic question.

Comment: I have the binary data and need to create text data.

Comment: Yes, but have you managed to load it into an RDD, as the beginning of your question suggests (but contrary to what your answer suggests) ?

Comment: Correct, I am not able to read in the binary data and that is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not from my use of 'pipe', but that 'textFile' cannot be used to read in binary data.  (Doh) There are a couple options to move forward.

1. Implement a custom 'InputFormat' that understands the binary input data.  (Many thanks to Sean Owen of Cloudera for pointing this out.)
2. Use 'SparkContext.binaryFiles' to read in the entire binary file as a single record.  This will impact performance as it prevents the use of more than one mapper on the file's data.

In my specific case for #1 I can only find one [project from RIPE-NCC](https://github.com/RIPE-NCC/hadoop-pcap) that does this.  Unfortunately, it appears to only support a limited set of network protocols.

Comment: Can you split the binary data out into multiple binary files?  That is how binaryFiles() is designed.  But I'm afraid that even then, there is a memory bottleneck as noted in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30704814/507544